# Plivo - How to get call_uuid in web sdk

Tags: plivo

Please Explain me how to get call uuid in there.
When i connect a call.
https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/web-sdk/make-outgoing-calls/

```
// Make outgoing calls
        function call() {
            if ($('#make_call').text() == "Call") {
                // The destination phone number to connect the call to
                var dest = $("#to").val();
                if (isNotEmpty(dest)) {
                    $('#status_txt').text('Calling..');
                    // Connect the call
                    Plivo.conn.call(dest);
                    $('#make_call').text('End');
                }
                else{
                    $('#status_txt').text('Invalid Destination');
                }
            }
            else if($('#make_call').text() == "End") {
                $('#status_txt').text('Ending..');
                // Hang up the call
                Plivo.conn.hangup();
                $('#make_call').text('Call');
                $('#status_txt').text('Ready');
            }
        }
```

Comment: anyone can help me

Comment: I'm wondering the exact same thing... Did you solve it yet or talk to Plivo's customer support?

Comment: Hello Richard can you solve this problem ?

Comment: Hi, yes, there was a misunderstanding on my side... All outgoing calls via the web-sdk calls your Answer URL in the application settings connected to your Endpoint, the answer URL does get the UUID that you need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WEB-SDK does Not provite the call uuid

```
 set callback url in xml and get both call uuid (DialALegUUID,DialBLegUUID)

 https://www.plivo.com/docs/xml/dial/#callbackurl-request-parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

The WEB-SDK does not provide the UUID, it does however call your `Answer URL` specified in your endpoint's application. From there you can redirect the call where it's supposed to, and use the provided UUID to start recordings and play voice messages etc...